# Easy algorithm-Leet code- Maximum sub array

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Struggling to wrap my head around this.

Maximum Subarray
Easy
Given an integer array nums, find the contiguous subarray (containing at least one number) which has the largest sum and return its sum.

A subarray is a contiguous part of an array.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
Output: 6
Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.
Example 2:

Input: nums = [1]
Output: 1
Example 3:

Input: nums = [5,4,-1,7,8]
Output: 23

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxSubArray(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        subarray1=[]
        subarray2=[]
    
        for n in nums:
            subarray1.append(sum(nums[nums.index(n):]))
            nums2=nums[::-1]
            subarray2.append(sum(nums2[nums.index(n):]))
            para1=subarray1.index(max(subarray1))
            para2=len(nums)-subarray2.index(max(subarray2))
            ans=sum(nums[para1:para2])
        
        if sum(nums)>ans :
            ans=sum(nums)
        
        if len(nums)==2 and sum(nums)< nums[0] or nums[1] :
            ans=max(nums)
       
        return ans
```

I'm don't understand the iterative logic and the answers from vids are coming up wrong.
My logic is to create an array summing the input array from both sides and use the index of max values on those 2 arrays to figure out the maximum sum sub array parameters.

My answer is supposedly wrong when copied onto leet code https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/

Been trying for hours, it's marked as easy. Im sure there is an easy iterative way of doing it but everything I've search is wrong so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i-1] > 0:
                nums[i] += nums[i-1]
        return max(nums)
```

This is a 2 pass `O(n)` time complexity solution with constant space.

How it works:
We add each element to its predecessor, provided the predecessor is greater than 0 (greater or equal would also do). The Idea is this: If negative numbers have managed to take it below 0, we discard the prefix and don't care about them anymore. But if some positive value is remaining, we add it since it's better than nothing.

At the end we look for the max value.

To make it one pass, you could just have a `best` value that at each iteration takes the max. Then you wouldn't need to loop over the array at the end again to take the max.

This is by the way [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm), if you are interested to further read about it.

Comment: should this not work against negative numbers, when nums[0] is a negative. In some cases the max sum subarray has negatives. Also how does return max nums work? you haven't assigned the num[1] += nums[i-1] to a variable? not clicking for me

Comment: It looks at `nums[i-1]`, if it's greater than 0, it adds `nums[i]` to it, if not it just keeps `nums[i]`, since adding a negative number would hurt our cause of getting the maximum subarray. At the end we iterate over the whole and take the max value.

Comment: While this works, the original one-pass Kadane's algorithm is more efficient, easier to understand and doesn't mutate the input list.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard logic to many of these problems.  Assume you know what subarray with the largest total is `nums[:n - 1]`.  Then what is the subarray with the largest total you can find for the subarray `nums[:n]`?

There are two possibilities:

- The new answer doesn't contain `nums[n-1]`.  In that case, it has to be the same answer as the old answer
- The new answer *does* contain `nums[n-1]`.

So. . .
The actual algorithm is that you iteratively go through the array, repeatedly adding a new element to the array, and keeping track of two answers:

1. What is the subarray with the largest total
2. What is the subarray with the largest total containing the last element.
   (This answer may be the same as the previous.)

When you then add a new element to the end of the array:

1. The subarray with the largest total is either (a) the previous largest total or (b) the previous largest total containing the last element plus the new last element or (c) just the last element.  Pick the one with the largest total.
2. The subarray with the largest total containing the last element is the larger of (b) or (c) above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm) to solve this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/) in `O(n)` time and space (and constant extra space). It is a simple dynamic programming algorithm:

```
class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        max_sum = -10**4
        current_sum = 0
        
        for n in nums:
            current_sum = n if n > current_sum+n else current_sum+n
            if current_sum > max_sum:
                max_sum = current_sum
        return max_sum
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution, although it exceeds time limit when the input list has a lot of elements. My idea is to try the sum of every sublist and update the max sum accordingly. There's a faster, but more complex approach by using "divide and conquer" method: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/discuss/1849465/Divide-and-Conquer-Approach-with-Python

My solution (works in 200/209 cases because of `Time Limit Exceeded`):

```py
class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        max_sum = - 10 ** 4

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(nums) + 1):
                s = sum(nums[i:j])
                if max_sum < s:
                    max_sum = s
        return max_sum
```

Comment: the solution by @user1984 is a lot better

Comment: The divide and conquer approach is O(n log(n)) which is very suboptimal, when this problem can be easily solved in O(n) and half the code.